# Best practice about data stored in Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an Ionic project connected with a PHP Backend, but I began storing some data in Firebase Database in order to make my app interactions faster.

I'm currently storing posts like this:

```
-/posts
   - /20  (User group ID)
     - /8  (User ID)
       - _postKey1
       - _postKey2
       - _postKey3
```

So when a user logs in the app, I get the group and user id from the backend, so I can get his posts from the Firebase Database using a ref like this `/posts/20/8/`.

That's working good so far, but in order to allow other user roles to see these posts, I'm storing only the post keys in a **subscribers** collection, for example:

```
- /subscribers
-   /88 (The subscriber id)
-     _postKey1
-     _postKey2
-     _postKey3 (subscriber has access to see these posts from /posts/ collection)
```

When I subscribers logs in the app, I have to get the post keys for this user, and then make a call for each one like this `/posts/20/8/_postKey1`, `/posts/20/8/_postKey2`, in order to retrieve the posts for this subscriber.

I'm pretty sure I'm building a spaghetti code right so I'm trying to get a light on the road of how can I do things better.

Thanks a lot!

**Code Example**

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/subscribers/88');

var postsRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/20/8');

// Get posts keys for this subscriber
ref.orderByChild('reverseDate').once("value", function(data) {
    // save post keys
    postKeys = data.val();

    // go trhough each post key
    Object.keys(postKeys).forEach(function(key) {

        // get the real post
        postsRef.child(postKeys[key].id).once("value", function(
            if(null !== data.val()) {
                // Append post to html list
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Does  firebase db PHP api not support queries ?

Comment: Hi! I'm not using the firebase PHP api since I'm getting the data in the Ionic app with JavaScript, but I haven't been able to do queries in there.

Comment: So you're using javascript library of firebase which documented at this link right ? 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Comment: Yup, that's correct, I'm using that one, just added an example of my code up there ^

Comment: That code looks fine. You'll either have to duplicate additional data, or do a client-side join (as you're doing now).

Comment: Thanks Frank. 

Yeah, I thought on duplicate data, but I'll have to update the same post multiple times when a user makes changes in the post content.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase database is not able to query along the value of child keys (more than one,which  is key1,key2 in the example below). So it's a good idea to keep collections as flat as possible. 
Something like that

```
posts:{  
   key1:{  
      postdata:"",
      author:userId,
      subscribers:{  
         userId1:postCreationTimestamp (or just a true val if you handle sorting with postkey),
         userId2:postCreationTimestamp
      }
   },
   key2:{...}
}
```

With this schema you can run [deep path queries](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) and sort/limit with by postCreationTimestamp

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("posts");
ref.orderByChild("subscribers/"+subcriberId).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

});
```

All we do here is duplicate subscribers of the user to all of him/her posts at post creation. **But it comes with a price**; if you want a users existing posts to be visible to new subscribers then you should run a background job which starts to add new subcriber id to all posts of revelant author

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tamer.

So do you suggest to keep that schema so I can get the posts > then check the subscribers to see if the current subscriber has access to this post?

Comment: yea when a user requests the feed list you can run a var ref = firebase.database().ref("posts");
ref.orderByChild("subscribers/tamer").limit(10).once("value", function(snapshot) {

});
query. 
All we do here is duplicate subscribers of the user to all of him/her posts at post creation. 
But it comes with a price; if you want a users existing posts to be visible to new subscribers then you should run a background job which starts to add new subcriber id to all posts

Comment: unsubscription is the reverse of it.as you know :). start a job (a cloud function maybe) which sorts&limits and  does the job partially until the end